# How can I share the Document Set title column?

Tags: document-set

I have a Document Set Content Type (let's call it, Request Packet).  Request Packet Content Type has the following fields

- Title (single line of text) [from Document Set]
- Description (multiple lines of text) [from Document Set]
- Request Code (single line of text)

This content type has an allowed Content Type (let's call it, Cover Sheet).  Cover Sheet has the following fields

- Title (single line of text) [from Document]
- Name (Filename) [from Document]
- Requester Name (single line of text)

I would like the Title field to be shared between the Request Packet (Document Set) and the Cover Sheet (Document).  Currently, the Title field is not listed as a sharable column.

How can I 'trick' SharePoint into sharing this column?

*Please note: I am limited in my environment to only SharePoint designer.  I cannot write code.*

**Edit:** Apparantly, when editing the content type, I can share the Title field.  However, when I apply it to a document library, it is no longer shared.